# Creating an Access JWT for my application from ID JWTs provided by 1..N third party authentication services

Tags: oauth, jwt, openid-connect

Scope: Thick client talking to REST API, with outsourced authentication.

I want to obtain an Access JWT that declares roles/permissions/claims that a person has against my application's API, but where the *authentication* of this person is to be done using potentially multiple (trusted, registered) external authentication services.

The external services do not know anything about the *permissions* that the person has in my application.

Is there a recognised OIDC or OAUTH flow where I obtain an *external identity* JWT from a trusted authentication provider, map the identity (e.g. alex@abc.com) in that token against a registered user account in my application (e.g. alex.101) and generate an Access and a Refresh JWT that declares "The holder is application user alex.101 who can read,write,report" that I can pass to my REST API endpoints? I would then expect to be able to use a Refresh token to generate fresh Access tokens.

I think I am asking... can I implement an Authorisation server for my application that accepts external identity tokens from trusted sources, identifies the corresponding application user from a pairing against the external identity, and queries the application user's permissions.

Is this a standard pattern? Is it an insecure pattern? Are there standard alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly how OpenID Connect is meant to be used. For your API you should have your own Authorization Server that issues tokens with permissions set by your system. Your apps will start an OAuth flow against your server to get access and refresh tokens. Your authorization server will start an OIDC flow against your chosen identity provider. As a result of this flow, you will get an ID token. Your authorization server can use the information from that token to authenticate the user and issue your own access token — exactly as you described in the question.

Comment: Thanks. I think I am confused about the user experience and the journey that the ID token takes. Does the ID token ever exist within the thick client?

Comment: In this scenario it doesn't. At least the ID token that you get from your federated providers. Your own authorization server can issue its ID token and send it to the client. Then the client will get an ID token and can use it e.g. to show messages like "Hello Michal".

Comment: Your AS starts an OIDC flow against the federated provider. It means that it will send a redirect response to the browser that will redirect the user to the /authorize endpoints of the provider. The provider will authenticate the user and send back a redirect response with an authorization code. This redirect_uri should be one exposed by your AS. The AS will get the response with the code and will exchange the code for the ID token. Then it will use the token to authenticate the user and issue an access token with your permissions, based on your data.